# GDB breakpoint in main() cannot access memory

Tags: c, gdb

My question is why when i set a breakpoint in main() with GDB i receive the error

```
    <0xffffffffffffe550: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffe550>
```

I wanted to set a breakpoint in main() so i could examine the memory in the stack. My disassembled code is this:

```
0x00000000004008e8 <+0>:     push   %rbp
0x00000000004008e9 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00000000004008ec <+4>:     add    $0xffffffffffffff80,%rsp
0x00000000004008f0 <+8>:     mov    %edi,-0x74(%rbp)
0x00000000004008f3 <+11>:    mov    %rsi,-0x80(%rbp)
=>  0x00000000004008f7 <+15>:    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x00000000004008fe <+22>:    cmpl   $0x1,-0x74(%rbp)
0x0000000000400902 <+26>:    jle    0x400920 <main+56>
0x0000000000400904 <+28>:    mov    -0x80(%rbp),%rax
0x0000000000400908 <+32>:    add    $0x8,%rax
0x000000000040090c <+36>:    mov    (%rax),%rdx
0x000000000040090f <+39>:    lea    -0x70(%rbp),%rax
0x0000000000400913 <+43>:    mov    %rdx,%rsi
0x0000000000400916 <+46>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
0x0000000000400919 <+49>:    callq  0x400670 <strcpy@plt>
0x000000000040091e <+54>:    jmp    0x400924 <main+60>
0x0000000000400920 <+56>:    movb   $0x0,-0x70(%rbp)
0x0000000000400924 <+60>:    callq  0x4006a0 <getuid@plt>
0x0000000000400929 <+65>:    mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
0x000000000040092c <+68>:    mov    $0x0,%esi
0x0000000000400931 <+73>:    mov    $0x400c6e,%edi
0x0000000000400936 <+78>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000040093b <+83>:    callq  0x400720 <open@plt>
0x0000000000400940 <+88>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)
0x0000000000400943 <+91>:    cmpl   $0xffffffff,-0xc(%rbp)
0x0000000000400947 <+95>:    jne    0x40096b <main+131>
0x0000000000400949 <+97>:    mov    $0x400c80,%edi
0x000000000040094e <+102>:   callq  0x400856 <fatal>
0x0000000000400953 <+107>:   jmp    0x40096b <main+131>
0x0000000000400955 <+109>:   lea    -0x70(%rbp),%rdx
0x0000000000400959 <+113>:   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%ecx
0x000000000040095c <+116>:   mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax
0x000000000040095f <+119>:   mov    %ecx,%esi
0x0000000000400961 <+121>:   mov    %eax,%edi
0x0000000000400963 <+123>:   callq  0x40098c <print_notes>
0x0000000000400968 <+128>:   mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
0x000000000040096b <+131>:   cmpl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
0x000000000040096f <+135>:   jne    0x400955 <main+109>
0x0000000000400971 <+137>:   mov    $0x400cb0,%edi
0x0000000000400976 <+142>:   callq  0x400680 <puts@plt>
0x000000000040097b <+147>:   mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax
0x000000000040097e <+150>:   mov    %eax,%edi
0x0000000000400980 <+152>:   callq  0x4006e0 <close@plt>
0x0000000000400985 <+157>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000040098a <+162>:   leaveq 
0x000000000040098b <+163>:   retq
```

And the code until my main is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "usefullfuncs.h"

#define FILENAME "/var/notes"

int print_notes(int, int, char *);
int find_user_note(int,int);
int search_note(char *, char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int userid,printing=1,fd;
    char searchstring[100];

    if(argc>1)
        strcpy(searchstring,argv[1]);
    else
        searchstring[0] = 0;

    userid = getuid();

    fd = open(FILENAME,O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == -1)
        fatal("in main() while opening file for reading");

    while(printing)
        printing = print_notes(fd,userid,searchstring);
    printf("-------[ end of note data ]-------\n");
    close(fd);
}

int print_notes(int fd,int uid,char *searchstring){
    int note_lenght;
    char note_buffer[100];

    note_lenght = find_user_note(fd,uid);

    if(note_lenght == -1)
        return 0;

    read(fd,note_buffer,note_lenght);
    note_buffer[note_lenght] = 0;

    if(search_note(note_buffer,searchstring))
        printf(note_buffer);
    return 1;
}

int find_user_note(int fd,int user_uid){
    int note_uid=-1;
    unsigned char byte;
    int lenght;

    while(note_uid != user_uid){
        if(read(fd,&note_uid,4)!=4)
            return -1;
        if(read(fd,&byte,1)!=1) 
            return -1;

        byte = lenght = 0;

        while(byte != '\n'){ 
            if(read(fd,&byte,1)!=1) 
                return -1;
            lenght++;
        }
    }

    lseek(fd,lenght*-1,SEEK_CUR);

    printf("[DEBUG] found a %d byte note for user id %d\n",lenght,note_uid);
    return lenght;
}

int search_note(char *note, char *keyword){
    int i,keyword_lenght,match=0;

    keyword_lenght = strlen(keyword);

    if(keyword_lenght == 0)
        return 1;

    for(i=0;i < strlen(note);i++){
        if(note[i] == keyword[match])
            match++;
        else{
            if(note[i] == keyword[0])
                match = 1;
            else
                match = 0;
        }
        if(match == keyword_lenght)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you compile this?

Comment: gcc program.c -g -o program

Comment: What happens if you use `start` in gdb instead of setting a breakpoint? Also, can you provide the entire code?

Comment: You seriously called the executable the same name as the source file?

Comment: How do you set the breakpoint?

Comment: @EOF he didn't, or it would've failed `gcc: fatal error: input file ‘program.c’ is the same as output file`

Comment: @Ishay Peled already put the entire code there, sorry i was kinda in a hurry. If i use start it throws the same error when i use the "x/24s $esp".

Comment: @EOF read the comment again.

Comment: @Eugene i used "break main" or "break *line of main()*"

Comment: Note that `x/24s $esp` will take the low-order 32 bits of $rsp, sign extend it to 64 bits, and print out the NUL-terminated character string at that address. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick my idea was to see the stack without initializing the main()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(gdb) x/24s $esp
0xffffffffffffe550: <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffe550>
```

On an x86-64 target, `$rsp` should be used. Using `$esp` will lead to incorrect results.

`$esp` is taken from the bottom 32 bits of the 64-bit `$rsp` register, and gdb treats it as type `int32_t`. `$rsp` in your example was probably `0x7fffffffe550`. Gdb's `x` command, which wants to use a 64-bit address, will take the bottom 32 bits of `$rsp`, `0xffffe550`, and sign-extend that to `0xffffffffffffe550`. That's almost certainly an invalid address; typical user-space addresses on Linux don't go above `0x7ffffffff000` or so.

Try `x/24s $rsp`. If you're trying to follow exercises out of an old book, you may be able to duplicate their 32-bit examples by giving gcc the `-m32` option, if it supports it. Then you can use `$esp`.

Comment: Very very nice catch!

Comment: @Mark Plotnick Yeah, you are correct. I completely forgot about that and yeah i'm doing exercises from a old book..i'm analyzing  the differences between the x86_x64 architecture and x86 but i completely forgot to try "$rsp" instead of "$esp". Thanks and thanks for the explanation it helped a lot